# PerformancePoint data source from Oracle

Tags: sharepoint, business-intelligence, sharepoint-2013, performancepoint, kpi

I have a requirement to create KPI and dashboard for which all data comes from Oracle. I am looking for getting this data into PerformancePoint to create KPIs..

Can anybody point me to the right direction on how to set my data source as Oracle tables? If this is not possible, what are other options available for me to get my data to SQL Server and then get it to display KPIs...

Will it be possible to use Business Catalog? or will I have to use some web services? Does anybody have how to go about this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I would think the best route to go would to possibly pull the Oracle data into a PowerPivot file and reference that in PerformancePoint. You could pull the data into SharePoint list through BCS or use SQL Server LinkedServer (but would just be tabular in PPS), but with PowerPivot or pulling it into a SSAS model that would probably be ideal and provide more functionality.